# Passing structure as parameter in RestApi using JAVA

Tags: java, rest, structure

I am basically trying to pass structures (complex objects) as arguments to a rest based service. Uptill now I know pass primitive types in URIs as `varname=value&varname2=value`.

My Question is how to pass structures containing multiple fields to the web service?

For example i have a Rest based web service that maintains employee records. Now if a particular record has 15 fields, then when using POST method how will a client be able to send those 15 values apart from send it in URL. 
So a simple object Employee having name, employee id, date of joining, etc.

I am using Eclipse for developing a java client.
My webservice is wrttien in C using gSoap having httpget and httppost plugins.
Requirement is to send complex structures as parameters to the service which can do processing on it and can return desired values.

Comment: @Elemental; Ok so i found a way to implement serializability while sending my message content to web service. Now The Next Step is how will soap server implemented using gSoap toolkit will be able to extract those values from message body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal solution used by most restful services I have used is to include JSON (or XML) in the body of the post message and return JSON (or XML) encoded data in the reply.

You will find support for JSON encoding and decoding in Java so it will be easy to implement.
It is also a much better solution than your current use of the URL for several reasons.